# United States Patent and Trademark Office (USPTO)

Tags: united-states, copyright, internet, software, international

if I used United States Patent and Trademark Office (“USPTO”) for my `game name` and publish google play store  then in this world no one can use my name to publish both App Store and google play or amazon store?

I found this one recently

> Lion Studios has acquired in the Love Balls trademark through its
>   continuous use in commerce, Lion Studios  is also the owner of the
>   following federal trademark application currently pending in the
>   United States Patent and Trademark Office (“USPTO”) Lion Studios (Serial
>   No. xxxxxxxx) for “game software” Filed October 9, 2017

above mean no one can used this name in the world to publish game to App Store.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### No

Registering a trademark in the USA prevents anyone using it *in the USA*. To achieve worldwide protection it would need to be registered in every country. However, trademark protection can also arise through usage without registration so Love Balls is already a trademark wherever it has been used.

This doesn’t mean other people cant use it. A trademark is limited by industry and is protected only to the extent that the other person’s use could cause confusion that that person’s goods and services are associated with the trademark owner. If you want to make a line of, say, adult toys called Love Balls this trademark for computer games wont stop you.

Notwithstanding, independent of any trademark, the logo has copyright protection in all of the countries that are signatories to the Berne Convention, that is, almost all countries.